# Prevent webservice URL from csrf

Tags: php, web-services, csrf

Create a webservice with csrf token for mobile app, for example

```
example.com?user=me&token=123abcde2dasd-q234sfFewr2
```

User call this URL first time and then I saved this token in my session.
 Now, I want if anyone call this URL again then return false.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than pass the actual token in the URL, place the token in a token story with a single use key.

For example, when you create the token, also create a key for it, then store it (for example in a database). Pass the key in the URL. When you receive the key, look up the token, place it in the session, then delete the key and token from your store.

This ensures the key is only used once and the token (which lives longer because you place it in session) is not given out.

This is one of many possible solutions, so you may need to be more specific with your question.